# Social Tables API: Event field values for Industry and Type are lost in browser UI

Tags: social-tables

I create an event using the POST /4.0/legacyvm3/teams/{team}/events function with the following data:

{
    "name": "My Event",
    "category": "event",
    "type": "Conference",
    "industry": "Corporate",
    "start_time": "2017-05-10T10:00:00.000Z",
    "end_time" : "2017-05-10T11:00:00.000Z",
    "spaces": [
        {
            "name": "My Room"
        }
    ]
}

and get the following response:

{"id":2474582,"user_id":138947,"team_id":"49992","name":"My Event","category":"event","venue_mapper_version":2,"start_time":"2017-05-10T10:00:00.000Z","end_time":"2017-05-10T11:00:00.000Z","uses_metric":false,"public":false,"attendee_management":true,"spaces":[{"id":4696516,"name":"My Room","event_id":2474582,"space_order":0}]}

All good. But when editing the event in my browser using the URL:

https://app.socialtables.com/?event=2474582

I am prompted to select a value for Industry and Type. Also, the start and end times are both appear as 11:00. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Start and end times look correct given that our API assumes you're using UTC (I see 6 and 7am EDT) when I open your event. It also was 10 and 11 in the response you posted.

Probably more importantly, you're using our legacy API and are therefore being pushed to our legacy product.  There is a 4.0/events endpoint available to use.  If you're writing your integration now I strongly recommend using these endpoints: https://developer.socialtables.com/api-console#!/Events/post_4_0_events

Comment: I have since found that if I close the event settings window and re-open it, the correct start and end times are shown (in UK time).

Comment: However, the industry and type fields remain blank. Is this a known issue in the legacy API and another reason to not use it?

Comment: I've tried using the post_4_0_events link but, when clicking Try If Out, get a message that Has time can't be blank. What is this field and how do I use it?